# Open boundary with Neumann Bc

Tags: matlab, boundary

How can I specify open boundary (full absorbing boundary) with Neumann boundary condition in MATLAB?
Wave is travelling to right from Edge `E1` and passes the Edge `E3` (below fig). MATLAB Code for incident Boundary:

```
fun1=@(location,state) 2*sin(2*pi/T*state.time)
applyBoundaryCondition(model,'dirichlet','Edge',1,'u',fun1)
```

How can I make the open boundary in MATLAB code (Edge E3)?

[image]